# ExpressionEngine Email Contact Form: confirmation email possible?

Tags: expressionengine

I work with expressionengine 5 and like to use the Email Contact Form. It is fast and needs little resources. Is there a way to have a confirmation email sent to the sender in a simple way? The user should receive the data of all completed fields. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Freeform can do this: https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform

Create a form and fields, connect the fields to the form and click on the email field to setup the notification.

Comment: Thanks. Freeform is a great Addon, but I avoid addons as long as possible. And for my little problem, the addon is exaggerated. Remains as an alternative PHP mail. ;)